# How to convert mysql if condition based value insertion to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, insert, conditional-statements

```
insert into agreement_form 
  set created = now(), 
      market_fk = (if (? = '''', null, (select m.id from market m where m.name = ?)))
```

The above query is inserting value for market_fk based on the param value and it is working in MySQL. How to convert the above query to postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `insert ... select`:

```
insert into agreement_form (created, market_fk)
select now(), 
       case  
          when ? = '''' then null
          else (select m.id from market m where m.name = ?)
       end;
```